# Is there a one-way method to convert binary number to hexdecimal number?

Tags: arithmetic, binary

I know how to convert the binary number to hexdecimal number but I first need to change it to decimal and then hexdecimal. It wastes my time and I want to know if there is any method to change it directly.

Comment: There is a [WikiHow article](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Binary-to-Hexadecimal) on this (which has a great comedic effect on me by the way)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know how to do now

Comment: This approach works when one base is a power of another, or with one more step of the two bases are powers of the same smaller number.

Comment: Not only is it wasteful to convert bases twice, the direct conversion is _much, much_ easier than either of the two conversions to or from decimal.

Answer (score 3):

The OP might be interested in the concept of a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble), used in computing.

If you are routinely examining bytes, you will probably have the following table of nibbles memorized, especially the pattern of red in the last column giving the binary equivalent of the first column showing the first $16$ hexadecimal characters.

[image]